# How to using command terminal in C in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to make a copy of a file in a folder and I want to write a function to calculate how much of the file remains to be copied.

I can implement it in the terminal with two commands.

The first command will get all files in the folder - before processing

`find . -type f | wc -l` => `counter1` -number of original file

And the second command will get all files already in the folder at current time.

`find . -type f | wc -l`  => `counter2` -number of the original file+ its coping

So, file_remaining = `counter1 * 2 - counter2`

`counter1` is multiplied by 2 because I want to make a copy file

How can I make a function to get the information from the two commands in the Ubuntu terminal using C or C++?

Comment: (Not that I fully understand your question as written, but) What's the specific problem you have with creating a C or C++ version of the program?

Comment: I using Ubuntu 12.04 and the C and C++ are standard version. I don't know version of C/C++.

Comment: …and what's the problem? Your question is really confusing as currently written.

Comment: My problem is how to using C or C++ to make function to get file remaining from two above command?

Comment: The answer is: Start by learning C or C++. Sorry I can't help more than that. Best of luck.

Comment: The output of those commands are best read with human eyes.  I recommend writing that functionality directly in C or C++, or using a library that does the same.

Comment: @DrewDormann: because I want to check every time, so I must make a function by C or C++.@danfuzz: I think you don't understand my question

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer. If you don't understand my question, please don't answer

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
   int main( int argc, const char * argv[] )

   {      
         FILE * fp ;
         char tstCommand[] ="find . -type f | wc -l";
         char path[100];
         fp = popen(tstCommand, "r");
         while ( fgets( path, 100, fp ) != NULL )
               cout << path << endl;

         pclose(fp);
         return 0;
   }
```